# L'Hospital's rule simplification with log

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2 + 4n}{\log_2(n)}$ applying L'Hospital's rule equals $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n + 4}{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Now my question is, if I have $\frac{2\infty+4}{\frac{1}{\infty}} = \frac{2\infty+4}{\frac{1}{0}} = \frac{2\infty+4}{0} = 0$ wouldn't that be wrong? Should I simplify first so I would have, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n + 4}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n(2n + 4)}{1} = \infty$ ?

Comment: Abusing notation, $\frac{2\infty+4}{0} = \infty$, not $0$.

Comment: Actually, $$\frac{2\infty+4}{\frac{1}{\infty}} = \frac{2\infty+4}{0} = \infty$$

Comment: what makes it $\infty$ and not 0 or undefined?

Comment: You're not really plugging in $\infty$ and getting $\frac{2\infty+4}{0}=\infty$. This is where really thinking about it as a limit matters. You should read $n\to \infty$ as "$n$ increases without bound," not "$n$ approaches $\infty$." As $n$ increases without bound, the numerator, $2n+4$, also increases without bound. Similarly, $\frac{1}{n}$ decreases to $0$. So, you're taking successively larger numbers in the numerator and dividing by successively smaller numbers in the denominator as you increase $n$ - that means the ratio itself increases without bound.

Comment: This makes no sense. You don't "plug in" infinity. That's just notation abuse. The only reasonable answer in my opinion is Arnaldo's. The rest of the answers are just abusing notation. @Angelo division by 0 is undefined if the numerator is not 0. Where it would be an indeterminate form. This would imply that this question is not fit for l'hôpital's. This happens because you abused notation. Also, you should check out on the full l'hôpitals statement. Everyone include you and I who doesn't know the full statement would actually fall for believing a limit does not exist in some strange cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

First,

$$(\log_2(n))'=\frac{1}{n(\ln 2)}.$$

Second,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2n+4}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} (2n^2+4n).$$

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldn’t use L’hôpital’s here. Logarithms grow really slow towards infinity. Whilst squares grow reasonably fast. This can be written as $\log_n(x) = o(x^2)$. Therefore, we get fast growth over slow growth (towards inifnity) which yields infinity.